# How to Open Maui mac application from web browser?

Tags: ios, json, macos, xamarin.forms, maui

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleURLName</key>
<string>com.xxx.xxxx</string>
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>fooo</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<string>Viewer</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

I have added URL type in plist but nothing works is there any solution that work in maui

Comment: This could be helpful [macOS/Windows AppLinks](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/6990)

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? I find some information that might be helpful : [Defining a custom URL scheme for your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app)